# FB.Canvas.setSize(); don't work when changing page

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, tabs, facebook-page

I have a facebook tab with multiple page. Everything work fine on the first page, the iframe is resized perfectly, but on the second page where the content is less than on the first page the iframe won't move it stay the same height as the first page. At first it was alse staying at the bottom of the page but FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0); fixed that. I tryed calling setSize with a specific size and nothing work. Also tryed most of the solution on here but nothing work.

Here is the code that I'm calling on every page before I close the body

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    <cfif structKeyExists(cgi,'https') AND cgi.https IS 'ON'>
    FB._https = true;
    </cfif>
    FB.init({
        appId   : '<cfoutput>#appId#</cfoutput>',
        cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        oauth     : true, // OAuth 2.0
        status  : true, // check login status
        xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        // user is connected but we don't have access to his province
        if(typeof response.status == 'string' && response.status == 'connected') {
            $('#erreurProvinceFB').css('display', 'block');
            $('.fb_iframe_widget').css('display', 'none');
            $('.sepOU').html('&nbsp;');
        }
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        <!--- met en post le nouveau signedRequest car l'ancien qui est en session n'est plus valide et que
        facbook ne renvoie pas un nouveau acces token si le tab est juste rafraichie et non reloader au complet. --->
        $('#signed_request').val(response['authResponse']['signedRequest']);
        $('#loginSignedRequest').submit();
    });
    FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 500 });
    //FB.Canvas.setSize();
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
};

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

This combination has worked well for me up to this point:

```
<body style="overflow: hidden;">

...

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '*ID*', // App ID
        channelUrl : '/channel.php', // Channel File
        status     : false, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    if ( window.location.protocol == 'https:' ) {
        FB._https = true;
    }

    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
};
</script>
```

Ensure your FB App ID is correct.

Comment: i had just FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(); at the start too, it don't work for me.. i don't know why :(

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisMorin Can you give us a link to your testing Facebook tab?